# my printer does not print with react-native-thermal-receipt-printer-image-qr

Tags: javascript, react-native, printers

I am trying to print with a bar code printer xprinter xp-237B my fanction works without error but the printer does not print however with another android application it has printed, I have tried another normal printer it prints without problem can you help me Please.
i use react-native-thermal-receipt-printer-image-qr

I don't know if the xp-237b printer is compatible with
react-native-thermal-receipt-printer-image-qr
I created an issue on github to find out